# Sqlite not opening db and not showing any error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the `react-native-sqlite-storage`, I have read through the documentation(https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) , I don't know why the db isn't opening, I am running the app on an android emulator, I have put the db in `android/app/src/assets`, The emulator isn't even showing an error, please any help will be great, I have been battling with this error :(

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,StyleSheet,Text,View} from 'react-native';

let SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')

export default class PrepopulatedDatabaseExample extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        record: null
    }

    let db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'test.db', createFromLocation : "~Herbo.db", location: 'Library'}, this.openCB, this.errorCB);
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM data', [], (tx, results) => {
            this.setState({record: "dskds"});

            // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.

            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let row = results.rows.item(i);
                console.log(`Record: ${row.name}`);
                this.setState({record: row});
            } });});}

   errorCB(err) {
    console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
  }

  successCB() {
    console.log("SQL executed fine");
  }

  openCB() {
    console.log("Database OPENED");
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                This is an example with sqlite3 and a prepopulated database. Enjoy!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                {this.state.record !== null ? 'Success: ' + this.state.record.name : 'Waiting...'}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );}}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
},
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PrepopulatedDatabaseExample', () =>  PrepopulatedDatabaseExample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your db `android/app/src/assets` to `android/app/src/main/assets/`

**Android DB Path**:
android\app\src\main\assets\.db

**iOS DB Path**:
ios/../www/.db

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: '<dbname>.db', createFromLocation: 1}, (open) => {}, (e) => {});
}
else {
    db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: '<dbname>.db', createFromLocation: '~/<dbname>.db', location: 'Library'}, (open) => {}, (e) => {});
}
```